# Laravel 4 - How to generate a controller with its methods

Tags: php, laravel, code-generation, laravel-4

I'm using `Jeffrey Way` `Generator` to generate my controller, but in `Laravel 4`'s version, I cant find a way to generate a controller with its list of methods.

This command: `php artisan generate:controller`, gives me a controller with a predefined template, but I want to declare these methods on my own.

Comment: With the command `php artisan controller:make controller_name` you can create a restful controller with all methods defined to CRUD operations. I don't know if that is what you want, but it's useful in many cases.

Comment: That's exactly what I get when I use `php artisan generate:controller controller_name` . what I want is to enter methods name (`actions`) to generate for the controller, directly with the command on the CLI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source, it doesn't appear that the Generator package currently does this.  You might send a feature request: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators/issues

Answer (score 5):

Go to the project route directory in Command prompt

```
cd c:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectName
```

then run the command `php artisan controller:make XYZController`

like this

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectName>php artisan controller:make XYZController
```

now it will creates a controller with the name XYZController.php in your Controllers folder i.e

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectName\app\controllers\XYZController.php
```

njoy!!.